# What is the value of $ \int_{x}^{1} \arcsin \left( \frac{2t}{t^2+1} \right) \text{d}t $?

Tags: integration, trigonometry

Is this result true? Wolfram doesn't seem to be able to evaluate the definite integral in the allowed time. $$ \int_{x}^{1} \arcsin \left( \dfrac{2t}{t^2+1} \right) \text{d}t = \dfrac{\pi}{2} - 2x\arctan x - \log(2) + \log(1+x^2) $$

Comment: Learn to recogize the expression $2t/(1+t^2)$.  It's the $y$-coordinate of a point on the circle whose $x$-coordinate is $(1-t^2)/(1+t^2)$.  So it's the sine of something.  And you're taking its arcsine.  (See my answer below for more specificts.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out whether it is true, differentiate, using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. Then use the fact that the integral on the left is $0$ at $x=1$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINTS:**

Make the substitution $t=\tan\theta$, and hence $\mathrm{d}t = \sec^2\theta~\mathrm{d}\theta$.

The identities $1+\tan^2\theta \equiv \sec^2\theta$ and $2\sin\theta\cos\theta \equiv \sin \theta$ will also be required.

You will be able to reduce the indefinite integral to

$$\int 2\theta\sec^2\theta~\mathrm{d}\theta$$

You can integrate this by parts by putting $u=2\theta$ and $\mathrm{d}v = \sec^2\theta~\mathrm{d}\theta$.
Once you have integrated $2\theta\sec^2\theta$, you will need to make the reverse substitution $\theta=\arctan t$ and then apply the identity
$$\cos(\arctan t) \equiv \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}$$

Finally, you will need to apply laws of logs to $\ln((1+t^2)^{-1/2})$.

**NOTE:**

Be careful with the domains of definition of the inverse trigonometric functions.

Comment: I decided to use the Weierstrass subsitution. Are there any fundamental differences between our methods? (I also needed the identities you recommended when I worked out the integral.)

Comment: @Khallil No difference whatsoever. You have a $\frac{\theta}{2}$ and I have a $\theta$. There will be a few factors of $\frac{1}{2}$ floating around and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{2t}{1+t^2} = \frac{2\tan\theta}{1+\tan^2\theta} = \frac{2\tan\theta}{\sec^2\theta} = 2\sin\theta\cos\theta = \sin (2\theta).
$$
So
$$
\arcsin\left(\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\right) = 2\theta.
$$
$$
dt = \sec^2\theta\,d\theta
$$
As $t$ goes from $x$ to $1$, then $\theta=\arctan t$ goes from $\arctan x$ to $\pi/4$.
$$
\int \theta\Big(\sec^2\theta\,d\theta\Big) = \int \theta\,dv = \theta v- \int v\,d\theta
$$
and so $v=\tan\theta$, etc.

Comment: I guess you didn't read the other answers...

Comment: @FlybyNight : And the authors of those other answers didn't read mine.  So we're even.  But why would you say that?

Comment: That would be quite difficult without a time machine. Your post was 14 minutes later.

Comment: @FlybyNight : So, as I said, we're even. But again, how do you conclude that I didn't read the other answers?